# Sentence with dass with three Verbs (Two modals)

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, conjunction, verbal-complex

I have a sentence:

> Ich werde diese Information mitteilen müssen.

How can I put that in sentence with "dass"?

> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information mitteilen müssen werde.

or

> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information müssen mitteilen werde.

What is the correct words order here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ich werde diese Information mitteilen müssen.

That's *Futur I*, werden+Infinitive. Please keep in mind, German speakers use *Präsens* for future events quite often, so

> Ich muss diese Information mitteilen.

is what you probably wanted to express. Why do I insist? Because

> Ich werde es tun müssen.

is a fixed phrase meaning *I don't want to do it but I have no choice.*

---

Your second pattern introduces indirect speech.

> Sie hat gesagt, …

Indirect speech calls for the *Konjunktiv I*. But the first person singular *Konjunktiv I* form of *werden* is the same as the *Indikativ* form, so you are allowed to use the *Konjunktiv II* form instead. Thus, both the following are correct:

> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information **werde** mitteilen müssen.
>
> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information **würde** mitteilen müssen. (preferred)
>
> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information mitteilen müssen **werde**.
>
> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information mitteilen müssen **würde**.

*Dass* introduces an object clause. Such clauses have a finite verb, not an infinitive. Here, that finite verb is again *werde* (or *würde*).

Last, why is the finite verb not in last position? It has to in dependent clauses, right? Yes, generally speaking. But rows of infinitives and participles are an exception, it's preferred to put it in front of the row instead.

---

In contrast, consider

> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information teilen muss.

Why *muss* isn't in *Konjunktiv I* mood but *Indikativ*? Isn't it indirect speech, too? It may be, but you have adopted her viewpoint. The listener understands you shared the information with her already.

This doesn't work with your *werde* example because, as written above, the *Indikativ* of first person singular of *werden* is the same as the *Konjunktiv I* form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the *werden*, the correct word order is:

> Sie hat gesagt, dass ich diese Information mitteilen müssen werde.

Why? The dependency of the verbs is as follows: **werden** (auxiliary) - **müssen** (modal) - **mitteilen** (main verb).

In a subclause with *dass*, the word order is verb last. If there is a main verb with one or more modal or auxiliary verbs, the order is the inverted order of dependency.